# VB WebBrowser control dropdownlist

Tags: html, vb.net, element

On this webpage: https://www.youtube.com/upload_defaults
I want to control the dropdown Category.

When I inspect the element I don't find the ID so I can't use GetElementById.

I have tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All

For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements

    If webpageelement.GetAttribute("value") = "category_id" Then
        webpageelement.SetAttribute("value", "20")

    End If
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly did not work?

Comment: I want to set Category on Gaming, but nothing happens.

Comment: I have a suspicion that to select an item in a `<select>`, you actually need to set the `selected` attribute of the child `<option>` element that matches the value you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting the element, you're right, the category dropdown does not have an id, but has a name: `category_id`. Your condition to check if your current looped HtmlElement is the category dropdown, is wrong. Replace this line:

```
 If webpageelement.GetAttribute("value") = "category_id" Then
```

With this:

```
If webpageelement.GetAttribute("name") = "category_id" Then
```

Or this:

```
If InStr(webpageelement.Name, "category_id") Then
```

Because, don't forget, `category_id` is the dropdown's name.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Tried both of your lines but I doesn't work.

Comment: Where do you have your code? Be sure to execute it after the document is completed. It works on my side.

Comment: Could you maybe drop your whole code that is working?

Comment: I have the same code as you, with the replaced line. I have it in the WebBrowser's `DocumentCompleted` event. If you put it in the form's load, it won't work.

Comment: I got only one problem left on the same page. Should I make a new topic or could I ask you here?

Comment: @Mathijs I tried to create a chat room with you, but wasn't able to. Ask me here, unless it's a different topic. At some point, when there will be too much comments here, a chat room will be automatically created for us.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My Rep is too low for a chatroom.

On the same page, I want to input text from a textbox into the "Description box". I have this code: WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("description").SetAttribute("value", TextBox5.Text)

But it is not working, but for example tags is working with this code (ofcourse his own ID)

Comment: @Mathijs This one's a little more tricky. You can't set its `value` attribute, since the description is a `textArea`, and it doesn't have a `value` attribute, unlike the `select` element. I'm looking for a solution, it won't be too long.

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks for clearing that up. I hope you can find a solution for me. Really appreciate all your help.

Comment: @Mathijs Normally, `WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("description").InnerText = TextBox5.Text` should work, but it doesn't seem to. I'm starting to think the page's javascript somehow forbids you from changing the textarea's innerText.

Comment: @Mathijs Sorry, in your case, It seems Youtube won't allow you to do what you're trying to do. But in the general case, the above code would work.

Comment: This really sucks to hear. Without that my tool is pointless. Is there anyway I can make it work?

Comment: @Mathijs I'm afraid I can't help you on that one. You should ask another question and see if someone more experienced knows how you could solve you problem. I'm sorry and wish you good luck.

Comment: Ye, only got a new problem...hehe

Comment: @Mathijs What's your problem? I'll help you resolve it when I arrive home in a few hours.

Comment: On that same page I want to click the "save" button. But since it has no id/name and stuff I don't know how to. Would appreciate it if you could look into it!

Comment: The answer you got at your other question is correct, but had a little mistake. [Check my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29813544/2835243) and accept his answer, it's a good one.