# VB WebBrowser click button

Tags: html, vb.net, button, click

On this web page: https://www.youtube.com/upload_defaults
I would like to call a function and then click the "Save" button in the upper right corner.

There is no ID or Name. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the distinct CSS class of the button: `account-save-button`

In VB.NET, use [HtmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) like this:

```
Private Sub ClickSaveButton()
    If (WebBrowser1.Document IsNot Nothing) Then 
        Dim Elems As HtmlElementCollection 
        Dim WebOC as WebBrowser = WebBrowser1

    Elems = WebOC.Document.GetElementsByTagName("BUTTON")

        For Each elem As HtmlElement In Elems
            Dim CssClass As String = elem.GetAttribute("classname")

            If ((CssClass IsNot Nothing) And (CssClass.Length <> 0)) Then 
                If CssClass.ToLower().Contains("account-save-button") Then 
                    elem.InvokeMember("click");
                    Exit For
                End If 
            End If 
        Next 
    End If 
End Sub
```

To verify it with just a web browser, try this from your browser's developer console; it works because youtube uses jQuery:

`$(".account-save-button").click();`

Or pure javascript: `document.getElementsByClassName('account-save-button')[0].click();`

For reference, here is the button's markup:

`<button class="yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-primary account-save-button account-action-button" type="submit" onclick=";return true;"><span class="yt-uix-button-content">Save</span></button>`

Other thoughts:

- This is basically screen scraping, which can lead to brittle applications when the page changes, etc.
- Google may already have a web service API for what you are trying to accomplish.. but that's a good question: 
  **What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  What is the context?** We may be able to suggest a better alternate solution.

**Update**:

I checked the [Youtube API Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/), but I don't see anything for setting preferences for upload defaults.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But unfortunately I don't get your code working.

Comment: It worked for me tho I did have to pull it out of context. If you show the actual code you are using it will be easier to put the answer in context with your solution.

Comment: Well I simply want if I press Button3 it will press the Save button. Could you provide me with the working code? Would be awesome.

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  ... and this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your solution is good, but be aware it should be `elem.GetAttribute("classname")` instead of `elem.GetAttribute("class")`